# How to sort an array so that I get a specific value at position one?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

If I have an array of:

```
var myArray = ["one", "two", "yay", "something", "something else", "some more"];
```

And want to rearange the array so that the value "yay" is at position 0

```
var positionOneValue = "yay";
var sortedArray = myArray ...
```

My attempt:

```
var sorted = myArray.sort((item) => {
    if(positionOneValue.match(item))
       return item;
     
    return null; // this is probably wrong
})
```

how do i accomplish this?

Comment: Should the other elements remain in place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check for the value and move the value to top with the delta of the checks.

```js
var array = ["one", "two", "yay", "something", "something else", "some more"];

array.sort((a, b) => (b === 'yay') - (a === 'yay'));

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the idea is to keep everything else in the same order, you can use `indexOf`, `splice` and  `unshift`:

```js
var myArray = ["one", "two", "yay", "something", "c", "b", "a", "something else", "some more"];
var yayIndex = myArray.indexOf("yay");
if (yayIndex > -1) {
    myArray.unshift(myArray.splice(yayIndex, 1)[0]);
}
console.log(myArray);
```